# Calculating the amount of Iron in an unknown solid sample

Tags: magnetic-fields, experimental-physics, metals, meteorites

So I want to take a sample of meteorite and figure out it's iron content. Whilst the overall iron content of the larger meteorite is known, how could I go about figuring this out for a given small sample from it, non-destructively?

Let's say to 3 sf precision. Preferably avoiding having to buy £50k pieces of lab equipment in the process.

Current vague ideas involve taking advantage of iron's diamagnetic nature, but not sure where I go from there?

Comment: I tested my only meteorite by hacksawing off a piece (not easy), dissolving the piece and let my quantitative analysis students analyze the solution to determine the iron and nickel content. Since you want non-destructive testing that does not require expensive instrumentation, e.g., XRF, you might just have to settle for seeing if a magnet sticks to your meteorite. Obviously not quantitative at all.

Comment: Yeh, this comes from the insistence that there is no cost-reasonable way to non-destructively measure the iron content in a sample of meteorite - which seems unlikely to me. I'm aware of method's use Beer's Law, but like you said, involves dissolving. I wonder if the force it attracts to a magnet could be used in some way?

Comment: Doubtful: my meteorite had a nominal certificate of analysis, I have no idea how trustworthy, stating that iron content was greater than 90% and nickel content was about 6.7%. Both iron and nickel are ferromagnetic, so this would complicate “magnetic estimation” of iron content. By the way, I bought the meteorite on ebay specifically so my class could see if I was ripped off and sold a melted chunk of ‘57 Chevy. Turns out I wasn’t. ;-)

Comment: I would send my sample to a lab for XRF analysis. Cost is approx. $100/sample. XRF is non destructive and accurate.

Comment: This one is Gibbeon meteorite, which is allegedly 90% Iron, 8% Nickel and some Cobalt. Hey... that '57 Chevy metal is getting on for 70 years old, it's worth something now! As a fellow space-rock-haver... I would really like to actually see the widmanstatten pattern on the meteorite, but everytime i clean it up and wax seal it, it's rusted within a day or two, obscuring it heavily. Any tips on that one?

Comment: It sounds like XRF is the concensus for the only cost-effective non-destructive testing. If anyone wants to put that as an answer, I'll mark it for future folks. Just in case anyone is looking for this quite specific question!

Comment: Yeah, XRF like @SteveSaban said. Mine is Campo del Cielo. I did not etch the cut surface. Instead, I sanded with successively finer sandpaper, polished with Mothers Mag and Aluminum polish, using a Dremel and buffing bit, then sealed with a fluoridated grease than can withstand almost anything (I used to use it on my excimer laser’s seals).

Comment: Here comes the low-bid: weigh it. Put it in water and measure the volume. Calculate the density. Be sure to look up your local value of $g$ at https://earth-info.nga.mil , https://mrdata.usgs.gov/gravity/ etc.

Comment: Does the weigh it approach not run into problems with the mixture of non-Fe components in the small sample (given that the small samples composition may not be representative of the larger meteorite)